# returning highest value with vlookup function

Tags: excel, vlookup

[image]

i have this kind of dataset and i have to fill the "tot depth" column taking the highest value from each progressive (col K).

i've tried with `==VLOOKUP(N2,K1:L13841,2,0)` but it gives me back the lowest value of the "P1" entry (-0.22).

the result i need would be :

- Progressiva  Tot depth
- P1           -1.15
- P2           -1.15
- P3           -1.67

Comment: Is your data always structured in such way that the results given per Progressiva is the last value? Also, a Pivot-table where you set value to *min* would do exactly what you are after.

Comment: In case of `P2` how it is `1.15`? Why not `1.67`?

Comment: Wy don't you use MINIFS? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599

Comment: Agreed, but maxifs.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have MINIFS, you might try this in cell O2:

```
=MIN(INDIRECT("L"&MATCH(N2,K:K,0)&":L"&IF(N3="",COUNTAK:K),MATCH(N3,K:K,0)-1)))
```

And drag it to the end of the list. It will work as long as:

1. K column contains only the uninterrupted list of "progressiva" values;
2. H column contains the uninterrupted complete list of single occurences of "progressiva" value;
3. both column K and column N are sorted in the same way.

Comment: unfortunately it won't work because since coulum K contains repeated values (such as P1,P1,P1) it is not the same length of col N that contains only the unique values of col K

Comment: I don't see the problem. Column K list lenght is not a problem to the formula, nor its difference in lenght with the column N. How the formula should have a problem with that?